# NET::FTP ruby on rails vist parent directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, net-ftp

```
a=Net::FTP.open('path', 'username','password')
a.chdir('any name of directory')
```

But how to visit the parent directory from `a.pwd()`

Comment: `a.chdir('..')` or `a.sendcmd('CDUP')` perhaps?

Comment: @PeterHuene both command worked correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `a.chdir('..')` to change to the parent directory if the host platform supports it (pretty much all platforms should) or use `a.sendcmd('CDUP')` to change to the parent directory in a platform-agnostic way.